# IP addresses in criminal cases

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, internet

Are IP addresses enough to convict someone of criminal activity?

So for instance, if someone was using their home WiFi network, which would have one IP address, then they use their mobile network which would have another IP address, would this be all that’s needed to convict someone of criminal activity if there was no proof that it was them that committed it?

Or are IP addresses not substantial enough?

Comment: Here's an actual UK court deciding a case involving IP addresses: http://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWPCC/2011/6.html

Comment: Possible dupe of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52840/is-an-ip-address-of-a-phone-an-admissible-piece-of-evidence-in-court/52850#52850 Worldie1234 and Remmmie have asked a number of very similar questions; possibly they are the same person.

Comment: @Just a guy Well, that was good old ACS:Law. With the judge saying that they had no case, no evidence, no nothing, and were just a bunch of scammers calling themselves lawyers. In more polite words.

Comment: There is always some additional information because merely using an IP address isn't in and of itself a crime. You'd need a lot of additional information to show that a crime was committed from that IP address (even if you know nothing more about the defendant). Ideally, you'd also get admissions of the lack of an alibi, and some sort of motive or M.O. that suggests that this person would have a reason to commit that crime and the technical ability to do so (depending upon the nature of the crime).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone be convicted of possessing illegal images if no evidence can be found the suspect’s computer?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67067/can-someone-be-convicted-of-possessing-illegal-images-if-no-evidence-can-be-foun)

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

If the prosecution proves beyond reasonable doubt that noone else could use that IP address at that particular time then yes.

But can it prove so? Maybe yes. Maybe not. Depends on the results of forensic examination of the device, network traffic, any other corroborating evidence etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need proof beyond reasonable doubt. The court will get expert witnesses to figure out how strong the evidence is.

First, someone will tell the court that if your home IP address has been used, how strong evidence it is that your computer or phone was used. And then if your computer or phone was used for a crime, it depends on the situation how much evidence it is that *you* used that computer or phone for the crime.

If the expert witness says there is no reasonable doubt that your computer was used for the crime, and the situation is such that there is no reasonable doubt that only you could have used the computer, then the IP address may be enough. If you share a flat with three other people, it's very unlikely enough evidence.

PS. To the comments: Yes, some hacker might be able to spoof your IP address. That’s where you’d need an expert witness who explains how much the IP address proves that your computer was used. But spoofed addresses can often be identified if one looks more closely, and it can be possible to prove that no spoofing happened in your case.

And yes, some hacker might be able to take control of your computer. That’s where someone has to find out how much your computer being used for a crime is evidence for you committing the crime. Such hacking will leave traces, and forensic examination can prove that your computer was not hacked.

Comment: The device could also be under control of remote hackers.

Comment: Could a phone be remotely hacked?

Comment: @Worldie1234 That's a question for [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) but by all means, yes.

Comment: So if it’s remotely hacked, then it would show up as that devices IP?

Comment: @Worldie1234 Yes, hackers do use hacked/zombie devices all over the world as their proxy/"VPN" service.

Comment: And could they do it over preloaded time? Months/years?

Comment: @Worldie1234 IP address spoofing is very much a thing...

Comment: @Moo but with spoofing, they wouldn’t get the replies from websites would they?

Comment: @Worldie1234 depends on which approach to spoofing they go with - there have been cases recently where huge blocks of internet traffic were stolen by Russia and other countries.

Comment: @Moo so if they were spoofing IP address’ for a long period of time, they could potentially get the reply from the website, would this mean they could use the website Normally?

Comment: @Worldie1234 yes.